# Including a global variable at the top of a layout to use in all controller/views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an includes file with this content `- @show = :dev` I need to include this file in my layout so I can use this variable everywhere. I've tried including it:

```
.content
  = render "includes/dev_live"
```

but it only works if I reference it in every view rather than just once in the layout. I can't just type in the variable as my site is hosted on two servers each with different variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [rails_config](https://github.com/railsjedi/rails_config) gem, it allows you to create settings files that are available in all controllers/views. For example have a settings file that reads:

```
:show
  'live'
```

then in your controllers/views you can access this by writing

```
Settings.show
```

(optionally converting to a symbol using to_sym if necessary)
By default the rails config gem has a local settings file which is not tracked by version control (for git anyway), so you can have different versions on different instances.